# How to change text color in HTML relate to background picture?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with changing color of one part of text on my website. I have background picture which has both red and blue color in it and I want to write down a title which will be red colored on blue part of the background and blue colored on red part of the background. How can I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you but you have 2 different background images: 1 is red colored and 1 is blue colored. You want to create two different pages where you use the 1st background image (red) in the first page with blue-colored text and then you use the 2nd background image (blue) in the second page with red-colored text?

Comment: Assuming your background image will move around a bit, and so will the text rendering due to fonts and such, I think you should utilize SVG for this.

Answer (score 1):

You might want something like this.

```css
.red{
  color: red;
}
.blue{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
     <span class="blue">Blue letters</span> <span class="red">Red letters</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Except it should be part of the text over blue background to be red and part of the text over red background to be blue.

Comment: The code can be manipulated to fit the background. It's just a basic concept of what they may be looking for.

Comment: No, how is this manipulated over a red-blue background image?